# Getting Claims from OAuth Authorization Service in ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I am using the following code to successfully get a token from my MVC web app. However I am unsure how to retrieve the claims that I have added. Should they be returned in the same response as my token?
Thanks!

Startup.cs:

```
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.Audience = "resource_server";
        options.Authority = "https://www.example.com/";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
    {
        options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
        options.AllowInsecureHttp = false;
        options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
        options.TokenEndpointPath = "/connect/token";
    });
```

Adding claims:

```
        identity.AddClaim("custom_claim", "value", "token id_token");

        foreach (string role in await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, role, "id_token token");
        }
```

This is my PostAsync result:

```
{"resource":"resource_server","scope":"openid profile","token_type":"bearer","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSU....","expires_in":"3600"}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `User.FindFirst("custom_claim").Value`?

Comment: My client is a Xamarin iOS/Android app which I don't think has an asp.net User object. I'm doing oauth login and then persist the token and claims in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should they be returned in the same response as my token?

Since you're specifying both the `id_token` and `token` destinations, your claims should be copied in both the access token and the identity token. You should be able to use any JSON parser to extract the claims you're looking for from the `access_token`/`id_token` properties.

Two remarks:

- In ASOS beta4, you had to explicitly add `scope=openid` to your token request to get back an identity token, even if you called `ticket.SetScopes("openid")`, which probably explains why there's no `id_token` property in the response you shared. This policy was relaxed in the next version.
- In ASOS beta4 (for ASP.NET Core RC1), access tokens were serialized using the JWT format. This is no longer true with the beta5 version, that uses an encrypted format by default. Don't try to read them from the client application: instead, use the `id_token`, which is meant to be consumed by the client app.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. I am deserializing my response, like this: AuthToken token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthToken>(result); Are you saying that I should be able to extract the claims from token.access_token? I haven't seen any examples of how to extract the claims. By any chance do you know of any examples? Thanks again!!!!

Comment: I tried this: var token = Convert.FromBase64String(json.id_token.split('.')[1]); but I get this error: FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Comment: Got the claims by doing this: var token = new JwtSecurityToken(token.IdToken); var claims = token.Claims; Hopefully this is a good approach.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't enforce any security check (e.g signature/issuer/audience validation). Depending on the OAuth2/OpenID Connect flow you're using, it might be a (terrible) problem. Also, if you're developing an ASP.NET (Core) client application, there are much better ways to achieve what you want (e.g using the OpenID Connect authentication middleware).